# Mi método registrar hecho con volley no me registra

Tags: volley

puedo iniciar sesión perfectamente según algunas guías que encontré pero no puedo registrar los datos de un usuario, aclaro que mi web services si funciona lo probé con postman, pero no se donde esta el problema en mi app, espero me puedan dar una pista de mi error.

al insertar los datos con postman mi webservices me da la siguiente respuesta:

```
{"estado":"exito"}
```

De tal modo mi método en android es el siguiente:

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, Http.URL_WEB_SERVICE + "registrar-usuario.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Usuario user = new Usuario();
                    Log.i("RESPUESTA JSON: ",""+response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject objResultado = new JSONObject(response);
                        String estadox = objResultado.get("estado").toString();
                        if(estadox.equalsIgnoreCase("exito")){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),objResultado.getString("exito"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progreso.dismiss();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("DATA_USER",user);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    progreso.dismiss();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            final String sEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            final  String sPassword =  password.getText().toString().trim();
            final String sNombre = nombre.getText().toString().trim();
            final String sMovil = movil.getText().toString().trim();

            Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
            parametros.put("nombre",sNombre);
            parametros.put("email",sEmail);
            parametros.put("telefono",sMovil);
            parametros.put("clave",sPassword);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Aun así no me agrega y en mi android monitor me regresa error osea lo siguiente:

```
 {"estado":"error"}
```

Comment: que trae el response? y como tienes tu codigo del servicio

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, deberías intentar meter los datos en el método post de la peticcion StringRequest para que pueda insertar datos, es decir que tu código quede de la siguiente manera:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, Http.URL_WEB_SERVICE + "registrar-usuario.php",
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Usuario user = new Usuario();
                Log.i("RESPUESTA JSON: ",""+response);
                try {
                    JSONObject objResultado = new JSONObject(response);
                    String estadox = objResultado.get("estado").toString();
                    if(estadox.equalsIgnoreCase("exito")){

                        final String sEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                        final  String sPassword =  password.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String sNombre = nombre.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String sMovil = movil.getText().toString().trim();

                        Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                        parametros.put("nombre",sNombre);
                        parametros.put("email",sEmail);
                        parametros.put("telefono",sMovil);
                        parametros.put("clave",sPassword);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),objResultado.getString("exito"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progreso.dismiss();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("DATA_USER",user);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                progreso.dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
}) {
    //adding parameters to the request
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

        return params;
    }
};
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

De esta manera, ya estas enviando algunos parámetros al web service. Espero te funcione.